# Как вычислить сумму массива чисел на Swift (аналогично примеру на Ruby)

Tags: swift, ruby

Данный код программы написан, на ruby с ипользованием блоков, а как написать такую же программку, только на swift

```
r=[45,5]
t=0
r.each do |f|
 t+=f 
end
p t
```

Что было понятней кто, использует си подобные языки, привожу такой же код программы, но только с ипользованием оператора while.

```
r=[45,5]
t=0
x=0
while x<r.length
t+=r[x]
x+=1
end
puts t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вариант 1.

```
let arrNumber = [45, 5]
var t = 0
for item in arrNumber{
    t += item
}

print(t)
50
```

вариант 2.

```
let arrNumber = [45, 5]
var a = arrNumber.reduce(0, +)
print(a)
50
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое за доброту !!!

Answer (score 3):

Это можно и на Ruby написать куда более лаконично:

```rb
r = [45, 5]
t = r.reduce(0, :+)
p t
```

[О `reduce` можно почитать в документации](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). Его можно развернуть для большей понятности:

```
t = r.reduce(0, :+) # Что за :+? Символ "+", обозначающий здесь метод
t = r.reduce(0) { |sum, element| sum.+(element) } # ведь + в Ruby это метод числа
t = r.reduce(0) { |sum, element| sum + element } # а это просто другой синтаксис того же
t = ((0 + 45) + 5) # Такие действия выполнит reduce для конкретно этого массива
```

В Swift 3, [говорят](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24795181/2076787), есть [аналогичный трюк](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907677-reduce):

```swift
let multiples = [...]
sum = multiples.reduce(0, +)
```